# Is there any replacemet for AWS RDS to create a database accessible for all instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to use a database accessible to multiple ec2-instances but RDS is a bit costly is there any replacement for RDS?

I am using ruby on rails for my project. Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.12

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rajat , You can create ur own instance and install DB into it . Problem with it ,you need to be aware (or u should have guys to manage it ) for backup experts .  RDS  makes you bit lesser responsibility to manage DB . You can take a snapshot of DB with simple commands or even through web GUI . So RDS makes DB things easy for you .

Comment: Thanks your suggestion it helped me a lot. Can u please also explain if my one instance is attached with a elastic IP say 1.2.3.4 then what about the other instance elastic IP to perform load balancing? Also how will i be able to connect my site after ELB?

Comment: Rajat , First create Load balancer , then attache two instances (its advised to have equal number of instances on both the zones) . To connect your instances you don't need to have elastic IP attached to the instance . load balancer gives you A record . you need to add this in your Route 53's A record entry . so that you can direct your website to your load balancer .

Comment: Thanks Bavihal for your guidance it really hepled me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a self managed EC2 based database instance. Create an instance with the desired capacity install the desired database flavor and create an end point to access it. You need to figure out the way to create an end point. Its possible.

here is the link `http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html`